# Non-stable vs non-linear orbits

Tags: orbital-mechanics

In orbital dynamics there are often two 'classes'- stable and non-stable, or periodic and non-periodic. Is this just a specific class of linear and non-linear harmonics? Would Klemperer's rosette orbit be an example of a non-linear orbit because it is neither closed nor stable?

Comment: The only linear (non-curved) orbital paths are directly towards or away from the more massive body, but the motion along these paths is non-linear due to acceleration from gravity.  **Thus, all orbital motion is nonlinear in $\mathbb{R}^3$.**  One might argue that a circular orbit is linear in a spherical coordinate system aligned perpendicular to the orbital plane, since then $r$, $\phi$, and $\dot{\rho}$ are constant, which I suppose is true, but not very useful.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia I interpreted the OP as asking about "linear harmonic oscillation", not linear paths.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Under that interpretation, there is no simple (linear) harmonic motion since gravitational forces scale with $r^2$.  The obvious only exception is when $r$ is fixed, for a circular orbit, in which the motion could be considered harmonic along each dimension in the orbital plain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#Uniform_circular_motion.